# jQuery animation is slower and lags in chrome on server side

Tags: jquery, performance, google-chrome, animation

My version of chrome is: 18.0.1025.168 m, Version of jQuery is 1.7.2.

Still when i try to animate:

```
$("#xyz").animate({ 'margin-left':'500px' }, 500, function(){
    //Do something (another animation).
    $("#abc").animate({ 'margin-left':'300px' }, 500);
});
```

Both `xyz` and `abc` animate smooth and quick in all the browsers (IE, FF and Chrome) in client side (on my computer).

But, when I upload it to the server, IE and FF animate smoothly as usual. Chrome animates `abc` smoothly. But Chrome struggles / lags severely while animating `xyz`.

Comment: what kind of elements are `abc` and `xyz`? Could you provide a demo page?

Comment: abc and xyz are divs... they are simply 2 div elements like this:  <div id="abc"></div><div id="xyz"></div>

Answer (score 0):

Do your animations on xyz happen repeatedly?  If so you may need to clear the animation queue.  Look into the jquery .stop() command.  The reason for your lag may be that jQuery is waiting for previous animations to complete before starting the next one.  If the lag seems to increase each time you animate xyz i would suspect this to be the cause.

Comment: No. Animations on both xyz and abc happen only on page load and just once. Besides, i already mentioned that they work fantastic on Firefox and Internet Explorer 6+. Chrome is the only problem and the problem occurs only on the server side. Offline version of the script does not cause any problems whatsoever on any browser.

Comment: When you say that problems only occur on the server side what exactly do you mean?

Comment: aamiri, I mean when i upload the contents of a website onto the disk space provided by the web hosting service provider. Ok... Seems like it doesn`t matter. I tested the script in linux with the same version of google chrome installed. And there is no problem at all. I wonder what`s wrong with my chrome in windows. Anyways, Thanks a lot for your help, guys!.

Answer (score 0):

boost the numbers to high value and try . i.e instead of margin-left':'500px' try margin-left':'1000px'  ... i dont know why but it worked for me... margin and top,left,right,bottom kinda lag in chrome.

Answer (score 0):

It is a well known bug in Chrome. It lags when the background images are full scale and even below that.

Read more at https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Iteration%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified&groupby=&sort=&id=92812
"background images lagging when scrolling in chrome is a bug!"